# Team Foundation Server Power Tools for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019, tfs-2015, tfs-power-tools

We use Team Foundation Version Control(TFVC) on on-prem TFS server. For quite a while it was possible to use TFS Power Tools (tfpt tool) from Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt. Lately we moved to VS 2019. Problem is that we can't find any proper TFS Power Tools for VS 2019. For example to do [undo checkout of unmodified files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544253/tfs-how-can-you-undo-checkout-of-unmodified-files-in-a-batch-file).

Does anyone had similar problem not being able to use tftp tools from VS 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone had similar problem not being able to use tftp tools from VS 2019?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This is a know issue about Visual Studio 2019. The Team Foundation Server Power Tools currently only updated to **TFS2017**, TFS2019 is not yet available.

Besides, Power tool has been renamed TFS Process Template Editor: [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor)

**Edit**: As of 10/16/2020 there is a [TFS Template Editor for Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte)

MS engineers are trying to develop it and will release it so that you can use it as soon as possible.

If you want to modify the work items, you can modify the work items by referring to the following documents:

[Import, export, and manage work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2019)

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there a plan to provide unshelve /migrate functionality again to vs2017 and vs2019? I think this is a greatly missed feature to migrate shelveset to a different branch

Comment: Saving you a click, [here's the 2019 version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte).

Comment: What do you mean with "it has been renamed"? The Power Tools were much more than just a way to edit the process templates and from what I can tell OP is not interested in modifying the process templates as in his question he gave the example of performing an undo checkout of unmodified files.

Comment: Does TFS template editor contains TFS shell extension?

Comment: This does not answer the OP's issue - "Problem is that we can't find any proper TFS Power Tools for VS 2019"

Answer (score 2):

For undoing unmodified files changes you can use this extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/52839174/6300406

[image]