# VS 2019 unable to add a file to TFS

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I'm currently using VS 2019 Professional and TFS as my source control. I've created an XML file on Notepad++ and placed it in a location that TFS is aware off in file explorer.

Usually with older version of VS, I would be able to right click the file and select "Add" under the TFS extension. From what I can see, this option is no longer available for 2019: [Team Foundation Server Power Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307522/team-foundation-server-power-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)

I've tried going down the path of using the dev command prompt and set a system variable with the

```
name: tfs
value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe
```

and once I attempt to run the following command: `tfs add myFile.XML` with the CD path set to where I want the file added, I receive the error:

```
'tfs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Was hoping to see if there's anything I was doing wrong here or if there's another way I can go around to achieve adding a file?

Comment: You don't use TFS for source control; you use **TFVC**. TFS is the platform that hosts TFVC repos. This is an important distinction because TFS supports both TFVC and Git repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anywhere stumbles across this in the future, on VS if you go to the Source Control Explorer Screen, navigate to the directory you'd like the file added to then right click anywhere on the screen and select Add items to folder